# Position fixed and width 100% element covering vertical scrollbar in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, scrollbar

I have a div with WIDTH 100% and position fixed on the top of the page. It covers the vertical scrollbar in IE when vertical scrolling is needed on the html.

What can I do to avoid this (I can't change the position fixed bit)?

Can I detect whether page need vertical scrolling onload/resize and change that static div's width using jQuery?

or

Solve it through CSS altogether?

Comment: Do you have more of your HTML/CSS or better yet, a link?  `position: static` and `width: 100%` isn't going to cause that on its own as those are the default properties of a div to begin with.

Comment: Sorry, I meant position 'fixed'. amended question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the problem: I accidentally attached `overflow:auto` on the `body` tag when it was only meant for the `html` tag.

Answer (score 1):

It is kinda hard to tell without seeing the page, but could you add a conditional stylesheet and move the div over 5px or so in ie so that doesn't happen?
 `right:5px`

The jquery code for this would be something like:

```
if ($(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
   $('#myDiv').css('left', '5px');
}
```